# How to get rid of ZFS signature on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ubuntu, freebsd, zfs

I am trying to set up hard drives that have previously been used with a FreeBSD installation to form a new LVM.

When running vgcreate, I get the message that zfs signatures were found. Due to a bug in vgcreate, it's useless to tell it to wipe those.

I tried using this script but the ZFS signatures are all over the drive: https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/26282/

Currently, my only chance to get rid of the zfs signature is to dd the whole partition. Doing so means that I have to wait about 20 hours per server.

Is there a more convenient way to simply get rid of all the ZFS signatures?

Comment: Depending on how many hours, it maybe quicker just to write a fix to vgcreate ;) - Sorry. Couldn't help myself. 20 hours to write 0's to a whole drive seems really slow btw.

Comment: Might have a look at the source of vgcreate. Was wondering about the slow write speed, too, but using bs=8M doesn't get me north of 26 MB/s. Maybe /dev/zero is a too slow source?

Comment: dd /dev/zero to /dev/null to test the speed, I doubt it's slow.

Comment: @djsmiley2k It takes about 11 1/2 hours to overwrite a 4TB drive at 100 MB/sec...

Comment: @AndrewHenle so Sascha's transfer is slow, for some reason then...

Comment: @djsmiley2k Or he's using 8TB drives and getting a bit over 100MB/sec.  I just ran the numbers for a true 4TB (4*1024^4) drive at 100MB/sec and came up with 11.6 hours.

Comment: Nod, but then he claims it's only 26MB/s, which is rather slow...

Comment: Did you try to `zpool labelclear` the devices?

Comment: zpool etc .aren't available on the system as it doesn't have ZFS functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Just because it's not made explicit here, and I was looking for how to do this to a boot-pool mirror that I fumbled (and only had an ubuntu machine to use to wipe the slate for a fresh start)...

The idea of using dd on SSD's is a bad one.  Very little searching effort will show you why.

Here's a simple, effective solution, that is very quick.  I do this work as root, 'cause I use freebsd most of time, which by default does not use sudo.  So if you need to, prepend sudo as appropriate.

We will assume you have the device available at /dev/sdx (not mounted).

```
# wipefs /dev/sdx*
```

This will show you the many instances of zfs signature (125 of them on one of the SSD's I am refreshing).  So this drive has stuff I want to eliminate.

```
# wipefs --all /dev/sdx
```

Actually does the deed -- 125 lines of output along the lines of:

```
/dev/sdx: 8 bytes were erased at offset 0x3a38ae0000 (zfs_member): 0c b1 ba 00 00 00 00 00
```

(the offset increases)

Executing the fisrt command again (the one without the --all parameter) will/should give you a null return, just to confirm.

And just 'cause I have bumped into this leftover before:

```
# gdisk /dev/sdx
... elision here ...
Creating new GPT entries in memory.

Command (? for help): x

Expert command (? for help): z
About to wipe out GPT on /dev/sdx. Proceed? (Y/N): y
GPT data structures destroyed! You may now partition the disk using fdisk or
other utilities.
Blank out MBR? (Y/N): y
```

Now you have a ready-to-use fresh drive.

Of course, if you are worried about data being recovered by another user, you *should* securely wipe the disk.  dd works fine for spin drives, but you need to find out the correct method for doing so with your SSD.  I have found good guidance in the past, elsewhere on the StackExchange sites.